# Absolute value of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

This question might be very simple, but I can't visualize how to get the absolute value of this complex number ($j$ is the imaginary unit):

$$\frac{1-\omega^2LC}{1-\omega^2LC+j\omega LG}$$

Thanks

Comment: What are $\omega$, $L$, $C$, $G$?

Comment: Could you clarify what $\omega, L, C$ and $G$ are?

Comment: They are just constants from an eletrical circuit.

Comment: Assuming all other symbols are real numbers, it might help to first multiply top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the denominator, then expand the denominator. This will give you a complex number of the form $x+jy$, which you should then be able to find the modulus.

Comment: That is it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, assuming $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\omega\space\wedge\space\text{L}\space\wedge\space\text{C}\space\wedge\space\text{G}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $j^2=i^2=-1$:

- $$|z|=\sqrt{\Re^2(z)+\Im^2(z)}$$

---

So, solving your question:

$$\left|\frac{1-\omega^2\text{LC}}{1-\omega^2\text{LC}+j\omega\text{LG}}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\omega^2\text{LC}\right|}{\left|1-\omega^2\text{LC}+j\omega\text{LG}\right|}=\frac{1-\omega^2\text{LC}}{\sqrt{\left(1-\omega^2\text{LC}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{LG}\right)^2}}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\left(1-\omega^2\text{LC}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{\left(1-\omega^2\text{LC}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{LG}\right)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(1-\omega^2\text{LC}\right)^2}{\left(1-\omega^2\text{LC}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{LG}\right)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{\omega\text{LG}}{1-\omega^2\text{LC}}\right)^2}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega\text{LG}}{1-\omega^2\text{LC}}\right)^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all other symbols are real numbers, it might help to first multiply top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the denominator, then expand the denominator. This will give you a complex number of the form $x+jy$, which you should then be able to find the modulus.